# How to unescape UTF-8 characters in Node (\u00f6)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, utf-8

I have a properties file which is encoded using ISO Latin but with special characters as UTF-8 escape sequences, for example the following string:

```
Einstellungen l\u00f6schen
```

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of `iconv`, `punycode` and `JSON.parse` yet none of them do what I need which is to convert these strings to a proper UTF8 format which works with JavaScript. No matter how I go about it the strings always have their UTF8 escape sequences when I print them.

Note that the file is a longer file with some line breaks etc if that makes any difference.

How do I read this file in a way which prints the correct characters?

Comment: FYI, JavaScript \u escape sequences have nothing to do with UTF-8. The number is the unicode codepoint [[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation)].

Comment: Have you tried `console.log("Einstellungen l\u00f6schen")` => `Einstellungen löschen`. JavaScript will automatically do the conversion for you.

Comment: `JSON.parse('"' + str.split('"').join('\\"') + '"')` or `str.replace(/\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, (m,cc)=>String.fromCharCode("0x" + cc))`

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that as well but for whatever reason it doesn't work when the string is parsed from the file which confuses me.

Comment: @Thomas `str.replace(/\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, (m,cc)=>String.fromCharCode("0x" + cc))` did the trick! Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it as soon as I can :)

Comment: because the string in the file ain't `"Einstellungen l\u00f6schen"`, but `"Einstellungen l\\u00f6schen"`, tiny difference with a huge impact

Comment: Yes, that must be it, it gets escaped as the file is read!

Comment: Please note that a text file is not interpreted as JavaScript source code.

Comment: In what way is your file ISO Latin?  If it really was, it would not need to escape "special characters", it would simply encode them each in 1 byte.  Do you mean ASCII?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either have to parse it as a string-literal, so the unicode-codes are parsed by the engine, therefore you have to wrap it in quotes before running it through JSON.parse().

```
JSON.parse('"' + str + '"');
//if you use " in your string, you would have to escape it
JSON.parse('"' + str.split('"').join('\\"') + '"');
```

or you search for the unicode-codes and replace them on your own

```
str.replace(/\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, (m,cc)=>String.fromCharCode("0x"+cc));
```

Comment: The second option is what I would probably do

Comment: Aye, the second option is what I went with.