# NodeJS RTF ANSI Find and Replace Words With Special Chars

Tags: node.js, escaping, rtf, ansi, ansi-escape

I have a find and replace script that works no problem when the words don't have any special characters. However, there will be a lot of times where there *will* be special characters since it's finding names. As of now this is breaking the script.

The script looks for `{<some-text>}` and attempts to replace the contents (as well as remove the braces).

Example:

**text.rtf**

```
Here's a name with special char {Kotouč}
```

**script.ts**

```js
import * as fs from "fs";

// Ingest the rtf file.
const content: string = fs.readFileSync("./text.rtf", "utf8");
console.log("content::\n", content);

// The string we are looking to match in file text.
const plainText: string = "{Kotouč}";

// Look for all text that matches the patter `{TEXT_HERE}`.
const anyMatchPattern: RegExp = /{(.*?)}/gi;
const matches: string[] = content.match(anyMatchPattern) || [];
const matchesLen: number = matches.length;
for (let i: number = 0; i < matchesLen; i++) {

    // It correctly identifies the targeted text.
    const currMatch: string = matches[i];
    const isRtfMetadata: boolean = currMatch.endsWith(";}");
    if (isRtfMetadata) {
        continue;
    }

    // Here I need a way to escape `plainText` string so that it matches the source.
    console.log("currMatch::", currMatch);
    console.log("currMatch === plainText::", currMatch === plainText);
    if (currMatch === plainText) {
        const newContent: string = content.replace(currMatch, "IT_WORKS!");
        console.log("newContent:", newContent);
    }
}
```

**output**

```
content::
 {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf600
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 Here's a name with special char \{Kotou\uc0\u269 \}.}

currMatch:: {Kotou\uc0\u269 \}

currMatch === plainText:: false
```

It looks like ANSI escaping, and I've tried using [jsesc](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc) but that produces a different string, `{Kotou\u010D}` instead of what the document produces `{Kotou\uc0\u269 \}`.

How can I dynamically escape the `plainText` string variable so that it matches what is found in the document?

Comment: It's **not** "ANSI escaping", but well [documented](https://web.archive.org/web/20190708132914/http://www.kleinlercher.at/tools/Windows_Protocols/Word2007RTFSpec9.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was to deepen my knowledge on rtf formatting as well as general text encoding.

The raw RTF text read from the file gives us a few hints:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf600...
```

This part of the rtf file metadata tells us a few things.

It is using RTF file formatting version 1. The encoding is ANSI, and specifically `cpg1252`, also known as `Windows-1252` or `CP-1252` which is:

> ...a single-byte character encoding of the Latin alphabet

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252))

The valuable piece of information from that is that we know it is using the Latin alphabet, this will be used later.

Knowing the specific RTF version used I stumbled upon the [RTF 1.5 Spec](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm)

A quick search on that spec for one of the escape sequences that I was looking into revealed that it was an RTF specific escape *control sequence*, that is `\uc0`. So knowing that I was able to then parse what I was really after, `\u269`. Now I knew it was unicode and had a good hunch that the `\u269` stood for `unicode character code 269`. So I look that up...

The `\u269` (char code `269`) [shows up on this page to confirm](https://unicodelookup.com/#latin/2). Now I know the character set and what needs done to get the equivalent plain text (unescaped), and there's a basic [SO post I used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37585756/5750392) to get the function started.

Using all this knowledge I was able to piece it together from there. Here's the full corrected script and it's output:

**script.ts**

```js
import * as fs from "fs";


// Match RTF unicode control sequence: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm
const unicodeControlReg: RegExp = /\\uc0\\u/g;

// Extracts the unicode character from an escape sequence with handling for rtf.
const matchEscapedChars: RegExp = /\\uc0\\u(\d{2,6})|\\u(\d{2,6})/g;

/**
 * Util function to strip junk characters from string for comparison.
 * @param {string} str
 * @returns {string}
 */
const cleanupRtfStr = (str: string): string => {
    return str
        .replace(/\s/g, "")
        .replace(/\\/g, "");
};

/**
 * Detects escaped unicode and looks up the character by that code.
 * @param {string} str
 * @returns {string}
 */
const unescapeString = (str: string): string => {
    const unescaped = str.replace(matchEscapedChars, (cc: string) => {
        const stripped: string = cc.replace(unicodeControlReg, "");
        const charCode: number = Number(stripped);

        // See unicode character codes here:
        //  https://unicodelookup.com/#latin/11
        return String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    });

    // Remove all whitespace.
    return unescaped;
};

// Ingest the rtf file.
const content: string = fs.readFileSync("./src/TEST.rtf", "binary");
console.log("content::\n", content);

// The string we are looking to match in file text.
const plainText: string = "{Kotouč}";

// Look for all text that matches the pattern `{TEXT_HERE}`.
const anyMatchPattern: RegExp = /{(.*?)}/gi;
const matches: string[] = content.match(anyMatchPattern) || [];
const matchesLen: number = matches.length;
for (let i: number = 0; i < matchesLen; i++) {
    const currMatch: string = matches[i];
    const isRtfMetadata: boolean = currMatch.endsWith(";}");
    if (isRtfMetadata) {
        continue;
    }

    if (currMatch === plainText) {
        const newContent: string = content.replace(currMatch, "IT_WORKS!");
        console.log("\n\nnewContent:", newContent);
        break;
    }

    const unescapedMatch: string = unescapeString(currMatch);
    const cleanedMatch: string = cleanupRtfStr(unescapedMatch);
    if (cleanedMatch === plainText) {
        const newContent: string = content.replace(currMatch, "IT_WORKS_UNESCAPED!");
        console.log("\n\nnewContent:", newContent);
        break;
    }
}
```

**output**

```
content::
 {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf600
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx560\tx1120\tx1680\tx2240\tx2800\tx3360\tx3920\tx4480\tx5040\tx5600\tx6160\tx6720\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 Here\'92s a name with special char \{Kotou\uc0\u269 \}}


newContent: {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf600
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx560\tx1120\tx1680\tx2240\tx2800\tx3360\tx3920\tx4480\tx5040\tx5600\tx6160\tx6720\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 Here\'92s a name with special char \IT_WORKS_UNESCAPED!}
```

Hopefully that helps others that aren't familiar with character encoding/escaping and it's uses in rtf formatted documents!