# JavaScript/NodeJS RTF CJK Conversions

Tags: javascript, node.js, escaping, rtf, cjk

I'm working on a node module that parses RTF files and does some find and replace. I have already come up with a solution for special characters expressed in escaped unicode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009576/nodejs-rtf-ansi-find-and-replace-words-with-special-chars), but have ran into a wall when it comes to CJK characters. Is there an easy way to do these conversions in JavaScript, either with a library or built in?

Example:

An RTF file viewed in plain text contains:

```
Now testing symbols {鈴:200638d}
```

When parsed in NodeJS, this part of the file looks like:

```
Now testing symbols \{
\f1 \'e2\'8f
\f0 :200638d\}\
```

I understand that `\f1` and `\f0` denote font changes, and the `\'e2\'8f` block is the actual character... but how can I take `\'e2\'8f` and convert it back to `鈴`, or conversely, convert `鈴` to `\'e2\'8f`?

I have tried looking up the character in different encodings and am not seeing anything that remotely resembles `\'e2\'8f`. I understand that the RTF control `\'hh` is `A hexadecimal value, based on the specified character set (may be used to identify 8-bit values)` ([source](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm)) or maybe the better definition comes from Microsoft RTF Spec; `%xHH (OCTET with the hexadecimal value of HH)` ([download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/d/d/5dd33fdf-91f5-496d-9884-0a0b0ee698bb/%5BMS-OXRTFEX%5D.pdf)) but I have no idea what to do with that information to get conversions going on this.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample RTF file?

Comment: @JonIles here ya go, https://gofile.io/?c=2jxFqa

Answer (score 0):

I was able to parse your sample file using [my RTF parser](https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit) and retrieve the correct character.

The key thing is the `\fonttbl` command, as the name suggests, defines the fonts used in the document. As part of the definition of each font the `\fcharset` command determines the character set to be used with this font. You need to use this to correctly interpret the character data.

My parser maps the argument to the `\fcharset` to a Codeset name [here](https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rtfparserkit/parser/standard/FontCharset.java) then this is then translated to a charecter set name which can be used to retrieve the correct Java `Charset`[here](https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rtfparserkit/parser/standard/Encoding.java). Your character set handling will obviously be different as you are working in Javascript, but hopefully this information will help you move forward.